# Offline voice recognition on Android using embeddedTTS

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I am interested in seeing if offline voice recognition is possible using the Google TTS on Android and have tried to make that work and not succeeded. I am working on an Android app that requires a user to speak a 'magic word' into the phone and the phone responds when it hears the right word. Voice recognition works perfectly when I am connected to the network but I need to make it work offline.

I was looking through the Android documentation and came across this: [KEY_FEATURE_EMBEDDED_SYNTHESIS][1] The documentation said to retrieve features using getFeatures(Locale) to see what features the engine supports. It returned two features: embeddedTts and networkTts for the Google Text-to-speech Engine, so the embeddedTts feature is available. In line 3 of the code below, I enabled this feature per the Android documentation but it seems to have no effect. I have also tried setting the networkTts feature to false and that didn't change the behavior either. I get the error "Can't reach Google at the moment" whenever I am not connected to a data network.

I am hoping someone here could help me understand how to use embeddedTts.

I am testing my app on a Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.1.1

Thank you.

Here is the relevant code:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        HashMap<String, String> localSpeech = new HashMap<String, String>();
        localSpeech.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_FEATURE_EMBEDDED_SYNTHESIS, "true");
          if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it could have heard
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        if (matches.size() == 0)
        {
            tts.speak("Heard nothing", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

        } else {
            String mostLikelyThingHeard = matches.get(0); 
            String magicWord = "Magic";
            if (mostLikelyThingHeard.equals(magicWord)) {
                //tts.speak("You got it!", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                tts.speak("You got it!", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, localSpeech);
            } else {
                tts.speak("The magic word is not " + mostLikelyThingHeard + " try again", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, localSpeech);
            }
        }

    }
    else {
        Log.d("APP", "result NOT ok");
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up speech recognition (also known as "voice recognition" and "speech-to-text") with speech synthesis (also known as "TTS" and "text-to-speech"). To answer your question, it's not possible to implement speech recognition using using speech synthesis APIs.

Comment: Hmm...so is there a way to use "voice recognition" offline?

Comment: @Alek This question has been asked many times, search for "android offline speech recognition"

Comment: I did and all answers recommend using third party tools like CMUSphinx or PocketSphinx. Is there no way to do it natively without using external tools?

Comment: @Alek please open a new question, if you ask a question via a comment to an answer to an unrelated question then your question gets much less visibility. Also, in your question define better what you mean by "natively" and why PocketSphinx is not good for you...